# Want to use GSM Asterisk AX4G card

Tags: voip, asterisk

Im a Asterisk newbie, i want to setup a simple PBX with inbound and outbound calling.
I have zeroed on "GSM Asterisk AX4G card" as the telephony card.

While purchasing this card on their website they also ask to select GSM Module (apart from the GSM AX4G card). What is this GSM Module? This card can be viewed at 
[Click here to view the card](http://www.atcomshop.ca/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=50:a10988fbb418856a25ae7260d867ead2)

Is this card reliable? Can i deploy a simple PBX with a single channel GSM card?

Apologies if my queries are too basic, Im newbie here please bear with me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to set up a PBX for a typical home/office, then you probably don't want this card, since this is a wireless card.
Try something like the TDM400P with 1 fxo module (to connect to the telco), and (if you want to use standard telephones) fxs modules. the TDM400p supports up to 4 modules total.

voip-info.org is a great resource, as is Elastix Without Tears by Ben Sharif. Available [here](http://www.netfonic.com/pdf/elastix-without-tears.pdf).

Comment: We will be using GSM network for making outgoing calls so in this situation i guess this card makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution you can buy a SIP/GSM external gateway like Portech.
The configuration is really simple, you just create a sip trunk on your asterisk box and register portech like any SIP hardphone/softphone.

Comment: Will check portech. I would like to know how good are Atcom's products. How reliable and how is after sales service of Atcom?